# Moving average using awk in all columns

Tags: shell, awk, moving-average

I have a data as:

```
2       2
3       3
4       3
2       2
1       1
56      4
3       2
4       1
2       2
4       2
5       5
3       3
5       6
6       4
```

I would like to print the moving average with each 5 past numbers for all columns.

Desire Output is:

```
2.4     2.2
13.2    2.6
13.2    2.4
13.2    2
13.2    2
13.8    2.2
3.6     2.4
3.6     2.6
3.8     3.6
4.6     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with three-rules utilizing a *"Sliding-Window"* for values stored in two arrays `a[]` and `b[]`. You simply fill each element using a counter `n` as the index, and then when `n >= 5` output the sum and `delete` the value at `a[n-4]` and `b[n-4]` (optional) and keep going. Your first rule is just that (with the addition of a loop and a sum of the last 5 values in each for the average.

Your second rule simply validates you have 2 fields and fills the `a[]` and `b[]` arrays. (you can add tests to ensure both field1 and field2 are numeric values -- that is left to you)

Your third rule is the `END` rule which computes and outputs the final sum, e.g.

```
awk '
    n >= 5 {
        suma=sumb=0
        for (i = n-4; i <= n; i++) {
            suma+=a[i]
            sumb+=b[i]
        }
        print suma/5"\t"sumb/5
        delete a[n-4]
        delete b[n-4]
    }
    NF >= 2 {
        a[++n] = $1
        b[n] = $2
    }
    END {
        suma=sumb=0
        for (i = n-4; i <= n; i++) {
            suma+=a[i]
            sumb+=b[i]
        }
        print suma/5"\t"sumb/5
    }
' data
```

(instead of looping to compute the sums, you can keep running sums and subtract the values you `unset` from the arrays -- up to you)

**Example Use/Output**

You can simply use an xterm and change to the directory where your `data` file is stored (change the name as needed) and *select-copy* the `awk` script above and *middle-mouse-paste* into the xterm. You will receive:

```
2.4     2.2
13.2    2.6
13.2    2.4
13.2    2
13.2    2
13.8    2.2
3.6     2.4
3.6     2.6
3.8     3.6
4.6     4
```

**Keeping Running Sums**

If you did want to keep running sums (`suma` and `sumb`) and remove the values at `n-4` instead of looping, (which would be slightly more efficient), you could do:

```
awk '
    n >= 5 {
        print suma/5"\t"sumb/5
        suma -= a[n-4]
        sumb -= b[n-4]
    }
    NF >= 2 {
        a[++n] = $1
        b[n] = $2
        suma += a[n]
        sumb += b[n]
    }
    END {
        print suma/5"\t"sumb/5
    }
' data
```

The output is the same.

Comment: ++ believe this one is more efficient

Comment: Yes, funny how your 1st thought isn't always the most efficient, but then as you start tinkering -- you find improvements along the way... Unless your Ed or Charles `:)`

Comment: @Kay, I rolled the edit back as the use of `$n1` using a shell variable should be handled with a `-v` option or `BEGIN` rule to make it an awk variable. Otherwise, the quoting and escaping of `$` becomes fragile. I like what you did to generalize and clean up the format though!

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I did mean `delete` -- glad `unset` is harmless and it must have once been used or is a synonym for something. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `awk` using 2 pass:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR == NR {
   a[FNR] = $1
   b[FNR] = $2
   for (i=FNR-4; FNR>= 5 && i<=FNR; i++) {
      sum1[FNR-4] += a[i]
      sum2[FNR-4] += b[i]
   }
   tr = FNR
   next
}
FNR <= tr-4 {
   printf "%.2f%s%.2f\n", sum1[FNR]/5, OFS, sum2[FNR]/5
}' file file
```

```
2.40    2.20
13.20   2.60
13.20   2.40
13.20   2.00
13.20   2.00
13.80   2.20
3.60    2.40
3.60    2.60
3.80    3.60
4.60    4.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, adding one more way of doing this. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$1
  b[FNR]=$2
  lines++
  next
}
FNR<=(lines-4){
  ++count
  for(i=count;i<=(4+count);i++){
    sum1+=a[i]
    sum2+=b[i]
  }
  print sum1/5,sum2/5
  sum1=sum2=""
}
' Input_file  Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: Okay, I see, you make 2 passes on the input. I'll have to remember that. I've seen a couple of times that is really good.

Answer (score 1):

All presented results are very memory intensive as the load the entire system into memory. While some delete the allocated memory, it is easier to just use a modular index. On top of that you don't really need to constantly recompute the sums (with floats I would argue differently if you have a high precision demand, but with integers it is not needed):

This solution assumes an equal amount of columns and a sliding window of `n`:

```
awk -v n=5 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {s[i] = s[i] - a[FNR%n,i] + $i; a[FNR%n,i]=$i } }
            (FNR >= n)  { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s" (i==NF?ORS:OFS), s[i]/n }' file
```

Comment: Excellent one!!